# Passing variables to JQuery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, sprite

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
    var pos = -411*i;
    var pospx = "{'background-position-x':'"+ pos.toString() + "px'}";
    $("#newsPix").delay(2000).animate(pospx, 1000);
    }
});
```

I'm a jquery beginner, and I'm trying to use animated sprites to make something similar to a slideshow. I've been trying to make this code work for hours but I'm not sure where the probelm is! I've checked the HTML and CSS and they seem fine. I think the problem lies in either passing a value to the animate method OR in string adding for the pospx variable. any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that reflects your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing a string, an object would be more appropriate as that is what animate() accepts :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
        var pos   = -411*i,
            pospx = {'background-position-x' : pos};

        $("#newsPix").delay(2000).animate(pospx, 1000);
    }
});
```

And `background-position-x` is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @EslamA.Hefnawy - no problem, you'll get more priveliges as you participate and post a few more questions / answers, and then it's a lot more fun.

Comment: in my case I follow the given code but not work if I set the value manually then it's working fine

`
for(var i = from; i<4; i++){ var p = $("#tab"+i).css('right'); if(p){ p = 300;//parseInt(p.replace('px','')); } //alert(position); position = {right: p}; $("#tab"+i).delay(2000).animate(position).animate(pospx, 1000); }`