# Velocity JS set a property dynamically

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I can change the value of left like so:

```
$.Velocity.animate(element,
    { left: '100%' }, 0
);
```

But how can I change that property dynamically with a variable, something like this.

```
var side = 'left';

 $.Velocity.animate(element,
    properties[side] = '100%', 0
 );
```

Then I can dynamically set the side to right or left.

Comment: By `dynamically set` you mean `while animation is running`??

Comment: no, before the animation, basically so I can decide which side of the screen it animates from, the full animation has a bounce effect.

Comment: `velocity.animate()` is a drop-in replacement for `jQuery.animate()` so I'd assume the same rules apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693113/passing-variables-to-jquery-animate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var props = {left: '100%'};
$.Velocity.animate(element,
    props, 0
);

// later just change props:
props = {right: '50%'};
// next animation runs with the new value
$.Velocity.animate(element,
    props, 0
);
```